# How can I use jQuery to snap a dropped item inside a div?

Tags: jquery, drag

I'm trying to recreate the World of Warcraft action bar for learning purposes.

So far I have the bar, and the individual slots are Droppable. What can I do so when the yellow div is dropped inside of the container, it is centered INSIDE the .item div?

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<script language="JavaScript">
    $(function () {
        $(".draggable").draggable();
        $(".item").droppable({
            drop: function (event, ui) {
                $(this)
                .addClass("ui-state-highlight")
                .find("p")
                    .html("Dropped!");
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="draggable">
</div>
<div class="bar">
    <div class="item">
    <p>a</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
    </div>    
    <div class="item">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this:

```
$(function() {
    $(".draggable").draggable();
    $(".item").droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.append(ui.draggable);    

            var width = $this.width();
            var height = $this.height();
            var cntrLeft = width / 2 - ui.draggable.width() / 2;
            var cntrTop = height / 2 - ui.draggable.height() / 2;

            ui.draggable.css({
                left: cntrLeft + "px",
                top: cntrTop + "px"
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**Edit:** I noticed you have some text in the target `div`.  If you want this to work with other elements in the droppable, you can position the dragged element absolutely and offset it using the `left` and `top` of the parent:

```
var width = $this.width();
var height = $this.height();
var top = $this.offset().top;
var left = $this.offset().left;

var cntrLeft = (width / 2 - ui.draggable.width() / 2) + left;
var cntrTop = (height / 2 - ui.draggable.height() / 2) + top;
```

And:

```
ui.draggable.css({
    left: cntrLeft + "px",
    top: cntrTop + "px",
    zIndex:1,
    position: 'absolute'
});
```

Notes:

- `ui.draggable` is the draggable item that was dropped on the droppable.
- `$this.append(ui.draggable)` appends the dragged item to the droppable `div` so that positioning can be done accurately.

Check out a live example here: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/F3sD3/

Comment: This works exactly how I wanted it to work. Thanks! Just another question, imagine if I have a lot of draggables, will this cause the code to break? Wouldn't referencing the same named item cause the computer to know what to select?

Comment: Regarding edit: I removed that <p> tag, that was just placeholder to see if the event fired or not. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Sergio Boombastic: Good question-- I assume you're referring to `ui.draggable`.  This object *always* refers to the item that was dropped, even if there are multiple elements that are draggable.  You can see this in action if you add multiple draggable elements: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/LEwg8/