# How can I change the position of a div using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'd like reposition a div on my website using jQuery.

Basically I have a toolbar with many slots. I'm using the Draggable+Droppable items from jQueryUI to handle the moving and dropping.

I'd like the dropped element to be positioned dead in the center of the container(droppable) to simulate a 'snap-to-center' effect.

How would I do this? I'm pretty new to jQuery, sorry for the simple question.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use jQuery to snap a dropped item inside a div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600265/how-can-i-use-jquery-to-snap-a-dropped-item-inside-a-div)

Comment: On drag end, find the element that was being dragged and manipulate the DOM to put it in the container.

Comment: @Phrogz: How can I get that element being dragged?

Comment: Does appear to be duplicate, but it also appears to be unanswered. Though it was only asked ten minutes before this one.

Comment: @SergioBoombastic Either latch onto it when you start dragging, or...there's something passed into your callback when you released. (Sorry, I remember having to dig for it each time I've needed it. If I could find it, I'd post it as an answer :)

Comment: @Phrogz: Thanks for trying to help, but saying 'latch' to it doesn't help me learn. I need a code sample for this basic (but necessary) process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This actually sounds more like a CSS problem.  I would suggest that you create a CSS rule that will center the divs in the container using a class attribute.  Then when you drag and drop the DIV element you can simultaneously apply the CSS class to ensure the div is centered.